# How to read a file having multiple lines, line by line in C++?

Tags: c++, file, multiline, getline

I am trying to read a file having multiple lines, where each line has a word and then a space followed by a short description of the word.

Example of the text file:

```
hello A type of greeting
clock A device which tells us the time
.
```

The fullstop (.) at the end represents that there are no more lines to read.

I tried an approach using a delimiter in the `getline()` function, but only succeeded in reading one line of the file. I want to store the first word (before the first space) in a variable, say `word`, and the description (words after the first space until a new line character is encountered) in another variable, say `desc`.

**My approach:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string filename = "text.txt" ;
    ifstream file (filename);
    if (!file)
    {
        cout<<"could not find/open file "<<filename<<"\n";
        return 0;
    } 

    string word;
    string desc;
    string line;


    while(file){
        getline(file,line,' ');
        
        word = line;
        break;
    }
    while(file){
        getline(file,line,'\n');
        desc = line;
        break;
    }    

   file.close();
    cout<<word<<":  ";
    cout<<desc<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The **output** of the above code is:

```
hello:  A type of greeting
```

I tried adding another parent `while` loop to the ones written above, having the condition `file.eof()`, but then the program never enters the two child loops.

Comment: to find better approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons

Comment: @buildsucceeded no, because eof is only set _after_ an unsuccessful read. But at Frexpe: have you tried using Google or the search function of this site? This question has been asked many times and there are a lot of examples online

Comment: Use `while(getline(file,line,'\n')) { desc = line;}` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need multiple loops, a single loop will suffice.  Read a line, and then use a `std::istringstream` to split it as needed. Repeat for each line.

For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string filename = "text.txt";
    ifstream file (filename);
    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "could not find/open file " << filename << "\n";
        return 0;
    } 

    string word;
    string desc;
    string line;

    while (getline(file, line) && (line != ".")) {
        istringstream iss(line);
        iss >> word;
        getline(iss, desc);
        cout << word << ":  " << desc << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```